# How to propagate changes while back navigation in android and ios?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, back-stack, popviewcontroller

I have a Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS app. The app has a data model called as PRODUCT. In various screens, we will list the products depending on queries or other criteria. Let's say that the user navigated from Activity-A (ViewController in ios) to Activity-B and further into C, D etc by selecting a specific product. Based upon the user interaction in Activity-D I need to update UI in all the other activities while navigating back from D to A . How can I propagate the changes down the back stack or how to update the UI accordingly while navigating back. The certain activity might contain the UI element directly in it while at other places  its part of a list. The product will have a unique id.

Comment: So you want to change `A,B,C's` UI when you do some specify action in `D`, am I right?

Comment: @jackHua yes, based upon the user action in the last activity/view controller I need to update the UI in all the screens in the back stack if the screen has that product to be precise

Comment: Is the answer resolved?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes with slight changes based on my requirements it solved the problem. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

**For Xamarin.iOS:**

There are several ways to pass data between ViewControllers. Here I recommend you to use `NSNotificationCenter` in your case. For example, if you want to change `A,B,C's` UI when you do some specify action in `D`, you can use the code below:

In the controller `D`: post a `Notification` in your specify action,you can add your personal requirments(for example:product ID, UI style) in dictionary(the third parameter):

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("changeUI",null, new NSDictionary("key1", 1, "key2", 2));
```

In the controller `A,B,C`, register as the observer of the `Notification` which named `changeUI`.

```
 NSObject notificationToken;
    void Setup()
    {
        notificationToken = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver((NSString)"changeUI", doChangeUI);
    }

    void doChangeUI(NSNotification notification)
    {
        NSDictionary dict = notification.UserInfo;
        Console.WriteLine("changeUI");
    }

    void Teardown()
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(notificationToken);
    }
```

So, once the controller `D` post a `Notification` named `changeUI`, all the observer will receive the `Notification` and perform the function predefined(Here is `doChangeUI`). You can get your personal requirments in the `dict` (`notification.UserInfo`) and update UI in the controllers.

You can refer: [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationCenter/)

**For Xamarin.Android:**

You can use `Broadcast-Receivers` in Xamarin.Android. It's almost same as NSNotificationCenter in Xamarin.iOS.

1.Creating a `Broadcast Receiver` in Activity `A,B,C`;

2.Publishing a `Broadcast` in Activity `D`;

3.Do your stuff when you received the broadcast

You can refer to the document for more detail:[broadcast-receivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers)

Comment: Just make sure that we are not adding the listeners multiple times invoking unnecessary multiple refreshes

Comment: @MidhunKumar It  would be better if you mark this answer. Happy coding:).